# Attack on Titan use of 一体

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate a scene early on in Attack on Titan but having some trouble with one line.

[Link to the scene in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eua71FNVMaE&t=60s)

This is what I have so far:

> 総員戦闘用意
>
> All units, prepare for battle

- 総員{そういん} - all members/all units
- 戦闘{せんとう} - battle
- 用意{ようい} - preperation

> 目標は一体だ
>
> the objective is one body ?

I don't quite understand what is being said here. Are they saying their objective is to get 1 body, as in to kill 1 titan, Or is it more along the lines of "we are share the same objective" ?

- 目標{もくひょう} - mark; objective; target​
- 一体{いったい} - one object; one body; unity​

> 必ず仕留め
>
> be sure to take it down

- 必{かなら}ず - always; without exception; necessarily; certainly; without fail; positively; invariably​
- 仕留{しと}め - to bring down (a bird); to kill​

> ここを我々人類最初の壁外拠点とする
>
> here we will make humankind's first base outside of the walls

- ここを我々{われわれ} - here we
- 人類{じんるい}最初{さいしょ}の - humankind's first
- 壁外{へきがい} - outside of the wall
- 拠点{きょてん}とする - to be based in (a place)​

Any general feedback is also most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here 体 is just another counter for animals, robots, statues, etc, which is usable whether they are big or small. So "one titan", not "the same objective". I think 体 is preferred in contexts where you have to refer to things matter-of-factly. Using 匹 or 頭 would not be wrong, but they would feel less "objective". See:  [Why was "一匹" used for Godzilla?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18099/5010)

Other parts of your translation look perfect to me.

Comment: Thanks naruto! So it's similar to the 台 counter for machines?

Comment: Yes, you can say 1体, 5体, 100万体, and so on.