# Why use 一本 in the expression 一本取る

Tags: etymology, expressions, counters

I was watching [an episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3T9Q4n1UKs) of ファニエスト外語学院 on judo.

At 6:26, the judoka remarked how his opponent ボビー could win him just by his horrid face, saying `「顔で一本取られた」って感じです`.

**I am interested in understanding why the 助数詞 `本` was used in the expression, especially when it is used for small, long things.** I looked up `一本取る` in ディジタル大辞泉 , which gives the definition  `柔道・剣道などで、完全に技が一つ決まること。` So I believe `一本` here houses the meaning 'in one go/shot/try', though I am not completely sure.

Comment: Just to be clear: Is your question about understanding the set phrase 一本取られる or a request for Japanese idioms that use counters? If the former, it may help contextualize things to keep in mind that in Judo, Kendo and other Japansee martial arts [一本](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ippon) is a unit used for scoring. If the latter, this question is very broad and I'm not sure it's feasibly answerable.

Comment: Hi @Mindful, I understand 一本取られる now, after realising 一本 has a special meaning in this context. That actually reminds me of a phrase I saw before, 男一匹, which uses the counter 一匹 on humans, conferring the nuance of masculinity. So I would just like to see a few more examples where counters are not used in their regular sense.

Comment: 男一匹 is not a set phrase/idiom, it's just deliberately using the 匹 counter to make the given man sound unthreatening/insignificant. As one would expect from the counter for small animals, it's diminutive, not masculinizing. This is addressed in some detail [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18099/why-was-%e4%b8%80%e5%8c%b9-used-for-godzilla/18100#18100). However, "interesting uses of counters" is a very broad question.

Comment: I'm content with just a few examples, given the broadness of this question. As for 男一匹, my dictionary gives the definition 一人前の男子であることを強め、また自負していう語。「男一匹約束はたがえぬ」. If I read correctly, I believe it is a boastful way of addressing oneself, interestingly with no condescension whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah it does appear that 男一匹 is a set phrase that carries the opposite meaning of what you would expect from it, my bad there. I'm not sure how common this usage as an idiom is though; probably need a native speaker to speak to that.

Comment: As a native speaker, I find it difficult how to interpret your "interesting uses of these 助数詞", as the 一本 is hardly a 助数詞 in my mind. And 男一匹 is an idiom, too, that you don't usually say 男三匹 or so.