# Can counter words also be nouns?

Tags: numbers, counters

According to people I've asked, and [this page](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/japanese/counter.html), if I pay 20 Australian dollars for my meal, it seems I say ni ju doru (20-ドル), and that ni ju-en doru (20-えん-ドル) would be ungrammatical - "dollar" acts as the counter.

Is it possible to refer to the Australian dollar as a noun in other circumstances (eg while talking about how the dollar fared on the exchange market)? If so, is this only because it's a loanword, or can the same apply with native Japanese words?

Comment: I think you meant to write ドル instead of ヅル ..

Comment: @Lukman: Thanks! [イソターネット](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/distinguishing-certain-characters-in-handwriting-and-print) desu. :(

Comment: When discussing exchange rates etc., Yen (or any other currency) are commonly used as nouns. To answer the more general question of your title: there are several counters that are also nouns (本, 面, 人 etc.), though quite obviously they do not have the same exact meaning...

Comment: @sawa: Does the rewording I've done make it better?

Comment: I still don't understand why you have えん there.

Comment: @sawa: Should it be katakana instead?

Comment: No. That is not the problem. えん and ドル are both currencies. I don't see why you have two currencies. It is like saying '3 meter inch'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search brought me to [this Amazon page](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%84%E5%86%86%E3%81%AF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%BD%E7%9B%8A-%E6%A6%8A%E5%8E%9F-%E8%8B%B1%E8%B3%87/dp/4492395008) for a book with title 「強い円は日本の国益」, which is an example where the counter for Japanese Yen 円 is used as a noun to refer to the currency unit, thus I believe counter words for currencies can be used as nouns.

[image]

EDIT: StackExchange engine breaks the Amazon Japan link again so here are the raw URL (you need to copy-paste): http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%84%E5%86%86%E3%81%AF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%BD%E7%9B%8A-%E6%A6%8A%E5%8E%9F-%E8%8B%B1%E8%B3%87/dp/4492395008

Comment: You are right that currency names can be used also as nouns.  Example: 円を売ってドルを買う市場介入 (market intervention (by the Bank of Japan) to sell the yen and buy the dollar).

Comment: I tried to fix the link to Amazon.co.jp by using [this workaround](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/256/the-server-rewrites-www-amazon-co-jp-to-www-amazon-com-and-breaks-some-links/260#260), but I rolled it back because it did not seem to work.  Sorry for the noise in the post history.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some coincidences, but for the most part I don't think you can just use a counter suffix as its own noun.  Unless you're explicitly using it as the topic of a sentence to describe what the counter means.

For example, `匹【ひき】` (counter for animals) could not be used as a noun by itself...unless your sentence is 「『匹』とは小さな動物を数える助数詞です。」("Hiki" is a counter for counting small animals.

I previously said that there are some coincidences.  For example, `一本【いっぽん】` means 1 cylindrical object.  Now `本` by itself *is* a word -- "book".  But you would never use it by itself in the context of a cylindrical object; only as a book.

Likewise, `〜頭【とう】` is used for counting "heads of animals" like cows, etc. (see posts [HERE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/counter-for-bears-or) and [HERE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/or-for-horses) for discussions about which animals can be counted this way).  `頭` by itself is `あたま` (or less frequently, `かしら` or `こうべ`) and means "head".  But you would never use `頭` by itself in the context of "heads of animals".

Comment: It is correct that counter words usually cannot be used as nouns.  Currencies are exceptions.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - I'm just thinking off the top of my head here, but as a rough rule of thumb, do you think that counter words which take 大和言葉 numbers are mostly stand-alone nouns? The only exception that pops into my mind immediately is "一重".

Comment: @rdb: I cannot think of many counter words that are 大和言葉, but you may be right.  Looking at [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E6%95%B0%E8%A9%9E), 枝, 棹, and 手 are also used as nouns (I guess that the usage as a counter word comes after the usage as noun).  (The list is not intended to be exhaustive.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - I meant to say that the numbers themselves were 大和言葉 (ひと、ふた、み、etc.), but now that I think about it, it's hard to come up with an example of ひと＋漢語　as a counter, so I guess it doesn't make much practical difference. BTW, this page has a pretty impressive listing for anyone who's interested:  http://www.benricho.org/kazu/a.html

Comment: @rdb: Sorry, I had misread your comment; but fortunately, as you said, it is not very different after all.

Comment: @rdb - Cool listing!  Thanks for the info.  I have a listing like that in my electronic dictionary, but I don't think it's as exhaustive.